How to edit an already existing routing metric in RHEL 9.3

Hi, based on the attachment, I would like to ask a question. I have configured a VM in VMWare and installed Redhat 9.3.
I configured the VM with 3 network interfaces and allocated it 3 different IPs from 3 different subnets. I would to make the 3 interfaces default via metric priority.
I want ens34 to be 1st default with metric 100, ens33 to be 2nd default with metric 200, and finally ens35 to be 3 default with metric 300, how can I achieve this?

please don't post pictures of code

Use nmcli to do this:
nmcli connection modify ens34 ipv4.route-metric 100
nmcli connection modify ens33 ipv4.route-metric 200
nmcli connection modify ens35 ipv4.route-metric 300
Not sure but you may have to down/up each interface after making the change.
